# Create equal table layout regardless of the data inside

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, flexbox

thanks for reading.

I'm trying to align a few tables on a page. Ideally, I want each table to stretch 100% width of its parent element. I just want the table layout to look the same, regardless of the data put inside of it. At the moment something is dictating how wide the tables are appearing and I can't figure out what it is.

As you can see the image shows that the tables are not similar in width. I want them all to look aligned if possible (similar / fixed width that they take on regardless if they have data inputs like "1", "2", "3" or long strings).

[image]

This is a partial snippet - there's more code to the page but I think this should be suffice

```css
.card-body {
    padding: 1.5rem;
    flex: 1 1 auto;
}

.table-responsive {
    display: block;
    overflow-x: auto;
    width: 100%;
}

.table {
    width: 100%;
    background-color: transparent;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="card-body"> 
  <div class="row">
        <div class="col-12">
            <h2><span class="text-warning">Room</span></h2><br>

            <div class="table-responsive">
                <table class="table">
                    <thead>
                        <tr>
                            <td></td>
                            <td></td>
                            <td>1<br>Living</td>
                            <td>2<br>Dining</td>
                            <td>3<br>Hall</td>
                            <td>4<br>Kitchen</td>
                            <td>5<br>Bath</td>
                            <td>6<br>Bed 1</td>
                            <td>7<br>Bed 2</td>
                            <td>8<br>Bed 3</td>
                            <td>9<br>Bath 2</td>
                            <td>10<br>Hall 2</td>
                        </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>
                        <tr>
                            <td>Design room temperature</td>
                            <td><strong>&deg;C</strong></td>
                            <td>21</td>
                            <td>21</td>
                            <td>18</td>
                            <td>18</td>
                            <td>22</td>
                            <td>18</td>
                            <td>18</td>
                            <td>18</td>
                            <td>22</td>
                            <td>18</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>Temperature difference</td>
                            <td><strong>K</strong></td>
                            <td>24.4</td>
                            <td>24.4</td>
                            <td>21.4</td>
                            <td>21.4</td>
                            <td>25.4</td>
                            <td>21.4</td>
                            <td>21.4</td>
                            <td>21.4</td>
                            <td>25.4</td>
                            <td>21.4</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td></td>
                            <td></td>
                            <td></td>
                            <td></td>
                            <td></td>
                            <td></td>
                            <td></td>
                            <td></td>
                            <td></td>
                            <td></td>
                            <td></td>
                            <td></td>
                            <td></td>
                            <td></td>
                            <td></td>
                            <td></td>
                            <td></td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>Length</td>
                            <td><strong>m</strong></td>
                            <td>7</td>
                            <td>4</td>
                            <td>5</td>
                            <td>4</td>
                            <td>3</td>
                            <td>3</td>
                            <td>3</td>
                            <td>4</td>
                            <td>2</td>
                            <td>1</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>height</td>
                            <td><strong>m</strong></td>
                            <td>2.5</td>
                            <td>2.5</td>
                            <td>2.5</td>
                            <td>2.5</td>
                            <td>2.5</td>
                            <td>2.5</td>
                            <td>2.3</td>
                            <td>2.3</td>
                            <td>2.3</td>
                            <td>2.3</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>Width</td>
                            <td><strong>m</strong></td>
                            <td>4</td>
                            <td>3.5</td>
                            <td>2</td>
                            <td>3</td>
                            <td>2</td>
                            <td>3</td>
                            <td>3</td>
                            <td>3</td>
                            <td>2</td>
                            <td>1</td>
                        </tr>
                    </tbody>
                </table>
            </div>

        </div><!-- /col -->
    </div><!-- /row -->

    <div class="row mt-4">
        <div class="col-12">
            <h2><span class="text-warning">Ventilation Heat Loss</span></h2><br>

            <div class="table-responsive">
                <table class="table">
                    <thead>
                        <tr>
                            <td></td>
                            <td></td>
                            <td>1<br>Living</td>
                            <td>2<br>Dining</td>
                            <td>3<br>Hall</td>
                            <td>4<br>Kitchen</td>
                            <td>5<br>Bath</td>
                            <td>6<br>Bed 1</td>
                            <td>7<br>Bed 2</td>
                            <td>8<br>Bed 3</td>
                            <td>9<br>Bath 2</td>
                            <td>10<br>Hall 2</td>
                        </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>
                        <tr>
                            <td>Air change per hour</td>
                            <td><strong>/h</strong></td>
                            <td>1.5</td>
                            <td>1.5</td>
                            <td>1.5</td>
                            <td>2.0</td>
                            <td>2.0</td>
                            <td>1.0</td>
                            <td>1.0</td>
                            <td>1.0</td>
                            <td>2.0</td>
                            <td>1.5</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>Air volume heated per hour</td>
                            <td><strong>m3/h</strong></td>
                            <td>105</td>
                            <td>52.5</td>
                            <td>37.5</td>
                            <td>60</td>
                            <td>30</td>
                            <td>22.5</td>
                            <td>20.7</td>
                            <td>27.6</td>
                            <td>18.4</td>
                            <td>3.45</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>Air spec heat capacity</td>
                            <td><strong>W/m3k</strong></td>
                            <td>0.34</td>
                            <td>0.34</td>
                            <td>0.34</td>
                            <td>0.34</td>
                            <td>0.34</td>
                            <td>0.34</td>
                            <td>0.34</td>
                            <td>0.34</td>
                            <td>0.34</td>
                            <td>0.34</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>Ventilation heat loss</td>
                            <td><strong>W</strong></td>
                            <td>871</td>
                            <td>436</td>
                            <td>273</td>
                            <td>437</td>
                            <td>259</td>
                            <td>164</td>
                            <td>151</td>
                            <td>201</td>
                            <td>159</td>
                            <td>25</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>Ventilation energy requirement</td>
                            <td><strong>kWh p.a.</strong></td>
                            <td>2078</td>
                            <td>1039</td>
                            <td>742</td>
                            <td>1187</td>
                            <td>594</td>
                            <td>445</td>
                            <td>410</td>
                            <td>546</td>
                            <td>364</td>
                            <td>68</td>
                        </tr>
                    </tbody>
                </table>
            </div>

        </div><!-- /col -->
    </div><!-- /row -->
</div>
```

Comment: You could either give them a % width or use `flex-grow: 1;`

Comment: Width: 100% is declared on multiple occasions (check CSS). I've also gone through each element in the table and added width: 100% manually - just to be safe - no change

Flex-grow doesn't seem to work either, I've never used it before though

Comment: So you wish to make the tables look even, the same width or size?

Comment: Just the width. They can vary in height, but i want them to occupy same width all the time

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check this, create a new HTML file and add the following code (the entire thing):

```css
   <style type="text/css">
      .card-body {
        padding: 1.5rem;
        flex: 1 1 auto;
    }
    
    .table-responsive {
        display: block;
        overflow-x: auto;
        width: 100%;
    }
    
    .table {
        width: 100%;
        background-color: transparent;
    }
    
    td{
      border: 1px solid #000;
    }
    </style>
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.6.0/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
      <meta charset="utf-8">
      <title></title>
    </head>
    <body>
    
    
    <div class="row mt-4">
            <div class="col-12">
                <h2><span class="text-warning">Room</span></h2><br>
    
                <div class="table-responsive">
                    <table class="table">
                        <thead>
                            <tr>
                                <td></td>
                                <td></td>
                                <td>1<br>Living</td>
                                <td>2<br>Dining</td>
                                <td>3<br>Hall</td>
                                <td>4<br>Kitchen</td>
                                <td>5<br>Bath</td>
                                <td>6<br>Bed 1</td>
                                <td>7<br>Bed 2</td>
                                <td>8<br>Bed 3</td>
                                <td>9<br>Bath 2</td>
                                <td>10<br>Hall 2</td>
                            </tr>
                        </thead>
                        <tbody>
                            <tr>
                                <td>Design room temperature</td>
                                <td><strong>&deg;C</strong></td>
                                <td>21</td>
                                <td>21</td>
                                <td>18</td>
                                <td>18</td>
                                <td>22</td>
                                <td>18</td>
                                <td>18</td>
                                <td>18</td>
                                <td>22</td>
                                <td>18</td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td>Temperature difference</td>
                                <td><strong>K</strong></td>
                                <td>24.4</td>
                                <td>24.4</td>
                                <td>21.4</td>
                                <td>21.4</td>
                                <td>25.4</td>
                                <td>21.4</td>
                                <td>21.4</td>
                                <td>21.4</td>
                                <td>25.4</td>
                                <td>21.4</td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td>Length</td>
                                <td><strong>m</strong></td>
                                <td>7</td>
                                <td>4</td>
                                <td>5</td>
                                <td>4</td>
                                <td>3</td>
                                <td>3</td>
                                <td>3</td>
                                <td>4</td>
                                <td>2</td>
                                <td>1</td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td>height</td>
                                <td><strong>m</strong></td>
                                <td>2.5</td>
                                <td>2.5</td>
                                <td>2.5</td>
                                <td>2.5</td>
                                <td>2.5</td>
                                <td>2.5</td>
                                <td>2.3</td>
                                <td>2.3</td>
                                <td>2.3</td>
                                <td>2.3</td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td>Width</td>
                                <td><strong>m</strong></td>
                                <td>4</td>
                                <td>3.5</td>
                                <td>2</td>
                                <td>3</td>
                                <td>2</td>
                                <td>3</td>
                                <td>3</td>
                                <td>3</td>
                                <td>2</td>
                                <td>1</td>
                            </tr>
                        </tbody>
                    </table>
                  </div>
    
            </div><!-- /col -->
        </div><!-- /row -->
    </div>
    
        <div class="row mt-4">
            <div class="col-12">
                <h2><span class="text-warning">Ventilation Heat Loss</span></h2><br>
    
                <div class="table-responsive">
                    <table class="table">
                        <thead>
                            <tr>
                                <td></td>
                                <td></td>
                                <td>1<br>Living</td>
                                <td>2<br>Dining</td>
                                <td>3<br>Hall</td>
                                <td>4<br>Kitchen</td>
                                <td>5<br>Bath</td>
                                <td>6<br>Bed 1</td>
                                <td>7<br>Bed 2</td>
                                <td>8<br>Bed 3</td>
                                <td>9<br>Bath 2</td>
                                <td>10<br>Hall 2</td>
                            </tr>
                        </thead>
                        <tbody>
                            <tr>
                                <td>Air change per hour</td>
                                <td><strong>/h</strong></td>
                                <td>1.5</td>
                                <td>1.5</td>
                                <td>1.5</td>
                                <td>2.0</td>
                                <td>2.0</td>
                                <td>1.0</td>
                                <td>1.0</td>
                                <td>1.0</td>
                                <td>2.0</td>
                                <td>1.5</td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td>Air volume heated per hour</td>
                                <td><strong>m3/h</strong></td>
                                <td>105</td>
                                <td>52.5</td>
                                <td>37.5</td>
                                <td>60</td>
                                <td>30</td>
                                <td>22.5</td>
                                <td>20.7</td>
                                <td>27.6</td>
                                <td>18.4</td>
                                <td>3.45</td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td>Air spec heat capacity</td>
                                <td><strong>W/m3k</strong></td>
                                <td>0.34</td>
                                <td>0.34</td>
                                <td>0.34</td>
                                <td>0.34</td>
                                <td>0.34</td>
                                <td>0.34</td>
                                <td>0.34</td>
                                <td>0.34</td>
                                <td>0.34</td>
                                <td>0.34</td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td>Ventilation heat loss</td>
                                <td><strong>W</strong></td>
                                <td>871</td>
                                <td>436</td>
                                <td>273</td>
                                <td>437</td>
                                <td>259</td>
                                <td>164</td>
                                <td>151</td>
                                <td>201</td>
                                <td>159</td>
                                <td>25</td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td>Ventilation energy requirement</td>
                                <td><strong>kWh p.a.</strong></td>
                                <td>2078</td>
                                <td>1039</td>
                                <td>742</td>
                                <td>1187</td>
                                <td>594</td>
                                <td>445</td>
                                <td>410</td>
                                <td>546</td>
                                <td>364</td>
                                <td>68</td>
                            </tr>
                        </tbody>
                    </table>
                </div>
    
            </div><!-- /col -->
        </div><!-- /row -->
    </div>
    
    </body>
    </html>
```

The output should look like this:
[image: Image of the output]

Comment: Unfortunately no different, mt-4 class simply adds a margin-top rule, I will add that information to the original post

Comment: Please check my answer now.

Answer (score 0):

Solved.

The problem was that another dev has put empty TR to provide a visual gap between specific table rows - this empty row had loads of empty TD that messed with width.

Thanks Shannon A